# Is there a way to make a countdown to a specific date in Lua?

Tags: lua, countdown

So I am just tinkering with Lua after hearing that it was more versatile than python, so I tried to make a countdown to one year, in the form of DDD:HR:MN:SC. If anyone could give me an example it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should exactly do what you want:

```lua
local function sleep(s)
  local t = os.clock() + s
  repeat until os.clock() > t
end

local function getDiff(t)
  return os.difftime(t, os.time())
end

local function dispTime(t)
  local d = math.floor(t / 86400)
  local h = math.floor((t % 86400) / 3600)
  local m = math.floor((t % 3600) / 60)
  local s = math.floor((t % 60))
  return string.format("%d:%02d:%02d:%02d", d, h, m, s)
end

local function countdown(tTbl)
  local diff = getDiff(os.time(tTbl))

  repeat
    print(dispTime(diff))
    -- os.execute('echo ' .. dispTime(diff))
    sleep(1)
    diff = getDiff(os.time(tTbl))
  until (diff <= 0)
end


countdown{
  day = 24,
  month = 12,
  year = 2019,
  hour = 0,
  min = 0,
  sec = 0
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! I totally wasn't expecting for someone just to do it for me. Thank you for putting the time in.

Comment: You call your function "sleep", but that's not what it does. You're just busy-waiting for a second, which keeps your program on the CPU when it really doesn't need to be. Specially for a countdown, 99% of your resource consumption will be for doing nothing. That's just pointlessly wasting resources and electricity.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer just rename it to stayAwakeAndDoNothingUntilYouAreDone(s) lol

Comment: Renaming it won't change the fact that it keeps the CPU busy though ;)

Comment: Yeah^^ But in this case I guess it's a negligibly utilization, I don't like the fact that `os.execute('sleep 1')` isn't working on every OS.

Comment: Here, I made the experiment: https://gist.github.com/DarkWiiPlayer/9567315d30cad8895c4bd6b0348f05c1 I'd say the findings are clearly on my side as far as performance is concearned ;)

Comment: How would you suggest a workaround for this @darkwiiplayer?

Comment: Depends. You can use `os.execute` to call `sleep`, you can use [luaposix](https://luarocks.org/modules/gvvaughan/luaposix) to sleep, or [ffi](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html) to make some system calls. [Many](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxsleep) [environments](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.timer.sleep) already expose some sort of *sleep* function to the user. Lua isn't python or ruby; there's no *one true sleep* or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.date`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.date) to retreive the current date as a table, then just build the difference by subtracting component-wise like this:

```lua
local function print_remaining(target)
   local current = os.date("*t")
   print(string.format("%i years, %i months and %i days",
      target.year-current.year,
      target.month-current.month,
      target.day-current.day
   ))
end

local function countdown(target)
   while true do
      print_remaining(target)
      os.execute('sleep 1')
   end
end

countdown {year = 2019, month=12, day=25}
```

If you want it to be cooler, of course you'd have to adjust what components are shown depending on how much time is left.

---

Inspired by @csaars answer, I changed a few things and ended up with this

```lua
local function split(full, step, ...)
  if step then
    return math.floor(full % step), split(math.floor(full / step), ...)
  else
    return full
  end
end

local function countdown(target)
   local s, m, h, d = split(os.difftime(os.time(target), os.time()), 60, 60, 24)
   print(string.format("%i days, %i:%i:%i", d, h, m, s))
   if os.execute('sleep 1') then
      return countdown(target)
   end
end

countdown {year = 2019, month=12, day=25}
```

The `plit` function is a bit more complex than it needs to be for this example, but I thought it'd be a nice chance to showcase how nicely some things can be expressed with variadic recursive functions in Lua.

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question, in addition I'll not use `os.execute('sleep 1')` as timer.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the countdown isn't past January 19, 2038. Unix Time won't work past that. Integer Overflow is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To obtain detailed information about the date, use the function `os.date` with the string argument `"*t"`. This call returns a table containing information such as minute, day, year, etc.

Using this, you could write a simple function that retrieves the current date and formats it however you prefer. In this example, I went with the `yyyy/mm/dd` format.

```
function format_date()
    local function tbl = os.date("*t")
    local date = string.format("%d/%d/%d", t.year, t.month, t.day)
    return date
end

print(format_date())

> 2019/11/19
```

The function `os.time` returns the time in seconds since the beginning of the current epoch. This could be another way to produce a countdown timer.

[Here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial) is a link to a page about the Lua OS library.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.